# Regular expression to match second or last decimal number in a string

Tags: regex

String:

```
<LF><CR>A214 pH/ISE,X00066,2.59,ABCDE,10/16/13 22:06:59,ABC1,CH-1,pH,7.00,pH,0.0, mV,25.0,C,100.0,%,M100,#35<LF><CR>
```

I need to match only the `7.00` - This number could be anywhere from `0.00 - 14.00` (its a `pH` reading).

Right now I can only come up with `[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}` which also matches the software revision number which appears earlier in the string (`2.59`)

Any help is greatly appreciated.

EDIT:  Thanks everyone.  I figured it out by using `[0-9]{1,2}\.[0-9]{2}(?=,p)`

Comment: Are all pH's preceded by `pH,`? I don't know the format but it looks like you have 2 pH's above?

Comment: Which language are you using?

Answer (score 1):

Simply find all entries and get the last:

```
>>> s = "A214 pH/ISE,X00066,2.59,ABCDE,10/16/13 22:06:59,ABC1,CH-1,pH,7.00,pH,0.0, mV,25.0,C,100.0,%,M100,#35"
>>> re.findall("[0-9]{1,2}.[0-9]{2}", s)[-1]
'7.00'
```

You can improve that regex by using the information that PH is between 0-14(first digit can only by one etc). Or better, just split by commas or use `csv` module.

Comment: THis is conditional on the use of python, codewise.  But the idea can easily be adapted to other languages.

Comment: Oh, sorry, was looking to the Python questions before, and assumed this was also.

Comment: It's dependent on that all the other values that exist after the desired value do not match the regex.

Answer (score 0):

If the format of the string is fixed, i.e. the data is in the 9th position if you split on `,` Use e.g. awk:

```
$ awk -F, '{print $8, $9}' input
pH 7.00
```

or using perl in awk-mode:

```
$ perl -F, -lane 'print $F[8]' input
7.00
```

Or this regexp

```
pH,(\d+\.\d{2})
```

See it line on http://www.rubular.com/r/3kkWNVBAi8

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can use that:

```
pH,(([0-9]|1[0-4])\.\d{2}),pH
```

group 1 match number that you need. And that control data